# Could you help me with this passage on Houston?

Tags: word-meaning

In August 1836, two **real estate entrepreneurs**—Augustus Chapman Allen and John Kirby Allen—from New York, purchased 6,642 acres (26.88 km2) of land along Buffalo Bayou with the intent of founding a city.The Allen brothers decided to name the city after Sam Houston, the popular general at the Battle of San Jacinto, who was elected President of Texas in September 1836.Houston was granted incorporation on June 5, 1837, with James S. Holman becoming its first mayor. In the same year, Houston became the **county seat** of Harrisburg County (now Harris County) and the temporary capital of the Republic of Texas. In 1840, the community established **a chamber of commerce** ** in part** to promote shipping and waterborne business at the newly created port on Buffalo Bayou.

1. I wonder what a real estate entrepreneur does In his job.
2. I am also wondering if anybody could tell me what the expression ** being a county seat of somewhere** means.
3. What do the phrase ** a chamber of commerece** and **in part** mean?

Answer (score 3):

> **Real estate**
>
> property consisting of land or buildings.
>
> **Entrepeneur**
>
> a person who sets up a business or businesses, taking on financial risks in the hope of profit.

Given those two definitions you should be able to ascertain the rest for yourself.

A **county seat** is the administrative centre of a county. A county is an administrative subdivision of a US state (in this case). [Wikipedia is your friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_seat).

A **chamber of commerce** is a network of local businesses, formed with the aim of furthering the interests of local business in general. [Here's that friend again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamber_of_commerce).